# How to add SCTP on Firewall of ubuntu

Tags: openvpn, sctp, ufw

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I have 2 remote computer which are connected via OPenvpn udp client server connection.

Strangely, I can send the 'INIT' msg of SCTP over the VPN, but there's no ACK or any SCTP connection establishment takes place. I have a feeling its happening because of probably firewall. So I wanted to add a firewall rules for SCTP.

Example. We can add firewall rule like - ufw allow 22/tcp

I want to add an SCTP firewall with a port number 132. But I am getting a

ERROR: Bad port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad port is a common error if you specified a bad protocol (ex: uppercase UDP/TCP by mistake).

In this particular case however sctp is not a supported ufw option, resulting in Bad port.

You'll need to look as using the iptables command directly.